sql query error Spring Boot Sql Query error
I am having issue this query  i am getting error when c doesn't have parent
   @Query("SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE (c.parent = NULL OR c.parent.enable  = true) AND c.enable = true AND c.alias = ?1") public Category findByAliasEnabled(String alias);
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Com.entity.category.Category.getId()" because "category" is null
i am tring to get data when c.parent is enable or c doesn't have parent

If this is a right answer you can select it as right, please.

an NPE is your code issue in how you are handling the lack of results - This isn't a query error as the query is executing. It is a logic error. You should show the SQL that is generated and executed (see logging for your JPA provider on how to get it shown) and verify the query against the database directly. As I put in the answer below, I suspect you are forcing an inner join which filters results that have nulls, but you'll want to verify the data directly in future.

  @Query("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.category.enable= true AND p.category.parent.enable= true  AND p.category.parent.enable= true   AND  p.category.parent.parent.alias LIKE %?1% OR CONCAT(p.id, ' ', p.name, ' ', p.alias, ' ',p.category.alias, ' ',p.category.parent.alias)   LIKE %?1%")
Page<Product> findAll(String keyword, Pageable pageable);

retrieve Product entities based on a keyword that can match various fields including the parent and grandparent category aliases, and product fields

The query is trying to access the c.parent.enable property even when c.parent is null, which causes a NullPointerException.
You can modify your query logic to explicitly handle the case where c.parent is null.
    @Query("SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE (c.parent IS NULL OR c.parent.enable = true) AND c.enable = true AND c.alias = ?1")
public Category findByAliasEnabled(String alias);


This query is the same logic used in the OPs; you've only switched the =null to a 'IS NULL'. Neither should work as by using c.parent.enable in the query, you are forcing an inner join over the c.parent relationship. The query needs to force using a left outer join

Try a JPQL query string of the form:
"SELECT c FROM Category c left join c.parent parent WHERE (parent is null OR parent.enable  = true) AND c.enable = true AND c.alias = ?1"

Defining the left join over the c.parent relationship should allow you to return category objects that don't have parents while still using it in filters in the query.
